# Keysight ADS User-Defined Models to AWR/Virtuoso

Tags: antenna-theory, software-development

everyone!
In ADS Keysight it is possible to create an item model - the so-called User-Defined Model.
This is C++ code that describes the Y-matrix of the component.

Is there the same possibility in AWR Microwave Office or Cadence Virtuoso - to create the same model same way?

Comment: I think your question is best asked on a group for RF engineers.

Comment: @wbg where I can find them?)

Comment: @ЕвгенийФедоров https://electronics.stackexchange.com